.gitlab-ci.yml save all script result into artifact
all!
I have .gitlab-ci.yml
build:
  tags:
    - $RUNNER_TAG
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - docs/
    expire_in: 1 week
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.23.2-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - mkdir docs
    - echo "Build completed" > docs/build.txt
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - /kaniko/executor --cache --cache-repo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $IMAGE_NAME
    - /kaniko/executor --cache --cache-repo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $IMAGE_NAME_LATEST


I want to save stdout of each command in script block into artifact, but I have no idea how to do it( or how to save full raw of the job.

This question is similar to: Gitlab: How to collect raw log into artifact?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Redirect the output of each command to a file listed in in artifacts -> paths - the same way you already do it in the line
- echo "Build completed" > docs/build.txt

Either do the same with the other script commands, but using >> instead of > in order to append instead of overwrite the previous entries:
- /kaniko/executor --cache --cache-repo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $IMAGE_NAME >> docs/build.txt
- /kaniko/executor --cache --cache-repo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $IMAGE_NAME_LATEST >> docs/build.txt

or to different file names if you would like the output split across multiple files:
- /kaniko/executor --cache --cache-repo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $IMAGE_NAME > docs/foo.txt
- /kaniko/executor --cache --cache-repo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $IMAGE_NAME_LATEST > docs/bar.txt

As you already have the docs/ directory listed in the artifact paths, all files under docs/ will be tracked as artifacts.
Otherwise you would need to specify all files which should be saved.
Note that the command redirection is just regular shell syntax, not specific to GitLab CI, and I am assuming Bash or a POSIX shell is in use in your container - there are other ways to append output of commands to files which you can use just as well, as long as the file being written to is listed under artifacts -> paths.
